# Dynamic service reference in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint, wss-3.0

I'm building a Silverlight application that interfaces with SharePoint Web Services.  In a windows forms application I'd create a web reference to my local SharePoint server, then change the Uri of the reference at runtime to point to whatever SharePoint site I wanted to use.  Silverlight doesn't seem to have web references, but similar functionality can be achieved with service references. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to change the Uri of the reference at runtime.  Is there a way to do this in Silverlight?  Or a better way of using  SharePoint web Services from Silverlight?

Note:  I need to access list item attachments, so owssvr.dll won't be sufficient (I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you are using WCF (to reference the Service), you can change the Address of the service like so:

```
MyServiceSoapClient soapClient = new MyServiceSoapClient();
mySoapClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(URI]);
// do call here
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be alot missing from this example.  soapClient vs. mySoapClient?
Endpoint.address is not a property of a service (SVC).