# How to update multiple Service References by creating a batch file?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have a project in VS 2010  which has multiple service references.
I want to update all of them at once using a batch file.
please help!!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using service references, you could consider configuring WCF services at runtime.

Some examples include:

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2009/02/23/silverlight-servicereferences-clientconfig-alternatives.aspx
2. [Dynamic service reference in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047761/dynamic-service-reference-in-silverlight)

Comment: this is an alternate path. I want the solution for multiple service reference updation simultaneously using batch file